# Bevel tool doesn't work with this model

Tags: modeling, bevel

B4 its been working fine, sort of. But this time it won't bevel this particular part. It basically adds something like a loop cut to the face.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try converting all those ngons to quads before bevel.

Comment: if nothing works, try to share at least a portion of your file (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)so others can inspect and perhaps resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before, I'm not sure if this will work for you but `ctrl+a -> apply scale` works for me

Answer (score 1):

Probably your problem is that the top part of the mesh is an ngon that bends around the corner connected to the edge you are trying to bevel.

I tried with a similar geometry: [image: does not bevel]

After dividing the top surface into two quadrilaterals, beveling works fine:[image]

I hope this helps.